# Passing return value from invoked method to generic method

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm building a modular API where people can contribute with their own endpoints by marking their resource methods with my custom attributes. Their methods become available if I load their dll's with my application. When a resource is requested my program fetches the data collection from the method they made (in their own classes), and applies sorting and filtering to them (probably with DynamicLinq) before sending the serialized response in JSON. All public fields (and maybe Properties) on these classes are considered fields in the api.

As you might realize, I only know the types of these data classes at runtime, but I was hoping I could invoke the endpoint methods and pass the returning `IEnumerable<SomeUnknownType>` to my Filtering method somehow anyway. I'm still kinda new to generics and the inner workings of C#.

My ideas have ranged from pure reflection, serializing to JSON at their end, and then parsing the string on my end, and now generics. Found this question:
[Using reflection to serialize files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500819/using-reflection-to-serialize-files), which featured some 'hack', but I didn't quite understand it and could not get it to work.

I only get DynamicLinq to sort my data when the collections are with a generic T.

Oh, and I'm stuck on .Net 3.5, so no dynamics.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Retrieves MethodInfo from a 'MethodHub' class, collected via Reflection at runtime.
    MethodInfo endpointMethod = MethodHub.GetEndpointMethod();

    // Invokes EndpointMethod. I know it will return an IEnumerable<T>, where T is unknown.
    object requestedList = method.Invoke(null, null);

    // The list should be passed to the 'Filter'-method, but it needs to be cast to its actual type first, so...
    Filter(requestedList);
}

// This is the method I want to pass the return value 'list' from 'EndpointMethod'
public static void IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(IEnumerable<T> inputList)
{
    // Filtering inputList with DynamicLinq
}
```

This is in some unknown class.

```
// This is the 'EndpointMethod'. The type of this IEnumerable<> is known only at runtime.
public static IEnumerable<SomeUnknownType> EndpointMethod()
{
    IEnumerable<SomeUnknownType> list = new List<SomeUnknownType>();

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Is `SomeMethod` a member of `SomeType`, or is it in the same class as `Main`, or is it somewhere else? And when you say `IEnumerable<SomeUnknownType>` for the return type, is that a typo that should be `IEnumerable<SomeType>`? Also, have you heard of MEF? It lets you load assemblies at runtime and bind plugins using attributes similar to what you're doing; no need to reinvent the wheel!

Comment: `SomeMethod` is one of the methods decorated with the custom attribute. It's not a member of `SomeType`, nor the same as `Main` here.
Yes, typo corrected, thanks!
I did not know about MEF. Cool stuff! But my program already injects into another, and I suspect getting it to work with something like MEF would be difficult.

Comment: Thanks! Does `SomeType` inherit from `SomeUnknownType` then, or is that another typo when you go to create the list? And the problem you're having is with the `GetSomeMethod()` call - you need to know what goes there to get the method using reflection or something like that? If that's the case, what information do you have about the method that can be used to look it up - its name, parameter types, return type, the type it's defined in, etc? Or are you having a problem with a different part of your code?

Comment: Wow, it's hard to phrase this! So, I edited the code above. My problem lies in me wanting to get ´requestedList´ into ´Filter()´ in the form of ´IEnumerable<SomeUnknownType´.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After invoking GetEndpointMethod, you can get the type of T of requestedList by `requestedList.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First()`. Try this code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
      MethodInfo endpointMethod = typeof(Main).GetMethod("EndpointMethod").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int)); //Replace Main with your class name

      object requestedList = endpointMethod.Invoke(null, null);

      var result = typeof(Main).GetMethod("Filter").MakeGenericMethod(requestedList.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First()).Invoke(null, new object[]{ requestedList });  //Replace Main with your class name
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(IEnumerable<T> inputList)
{
  return inputList;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> EndpointMethod<T>()
{
  IEnumerable<T> list = new List<T>();

  return list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is now working! However, I had to remove the argument `typeof(int)` in `MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int))`. I don't know the reason you put it there, but it's only working without it.

Comment: I was testing with List<int> and forgot to remove it :)