# Using generic type variable for NHibernate query

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I use a variable as type for calling an NHibernate query? My code looks (simplyfied) like this:

```
public string MyFunction()
{
    var myVar = typeof(MyModel);
    var myVar2 = ExecQuery<myVar>();
}

private List<T> ExecQuery<T>()
{
    var result = sessionService.GetDefaultSession()
         .Query<T>()
         .ToList();

    return result;
}
```

MyModel looks as follows:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
}
```

And the mapping:

```
public class MyModelMapping : ClassMapping<MyModel>
{
    public MyModelMapping()
    {
        Id(a => a.Id, b => b.Generator(Generators.Identity));

        Property(a => a.Name, b =>
        {
            b.NotNullable(true);
        });
    }
}
```

I get the error: `myVar` is a variable but is used like a type.

Any ideas? Thanks:)

Comment: In case you're actually trying to call `ExecQuery<T>` with the type only known at runtime, check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325156/calling-generic-method-with-a-type-argument-known-only-at-execution-time

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the type like this

```
public string MyFunction()
{
    var myVar2 = ExecQuery<MyModel>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I know about that way, but under my conditions it has to be the variable to be given as `ExecQuery<myVar>`

Comment: so, that means it's possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302577/how-to-use-typeof-or-gettype-as-generics-template

Comment: @Thiery V could possibly be, but I don't get how I can solve this now...can u help me maybe?